# Can we include a survey of dark theme vs light theme on the next yearly survey

Tags: themes, survey

We do that whole yearly survey, and I was looking for the percentages of dark theme vs light theme and couldn't find any info on it; thus I figured that it could be a question on the next survey. If there are other resources that give this information, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: There was a question on it in the 2015 survey, I wonder how it has changed though... https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2015#tech-ide